# Simple Laplace equation with peculiar boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a solution to this problem:

$$\nabla^2 f = 0$$
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}f(r,\theta)=1$$
$$f(R,\theta)=\cos(\theta/2)$$

on the domain constituted by the the whole real plane minus the circle of radius $R$.

If I proceed by using the general solution obtained by separating the variables (with the right periodicity):

$$f(r,\theta)=A_0+\sum_{k=1}r^{-k/2}[A_k\cos(k\theta/2)+B_k\sin(k\theta/2)]$$

I should have $A_0=1$, because of the boundary condition at infinity. But then I do not know how to calculate the coefficients $A_k, B_k$ when I impose the other boundary condition:

$$f(R,\theta)=\cos(\theta/2)=1+\sum_{k=1}R^{-k/2}[A_k\cos(k\theta/2)+B_k\sin(k\theta/2)]$$

Is there a solution to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your sum does not satisfy the laplace equation. At $\theta=\pm \pi$, it's not even continuously differentiable, so $\nabla^2$ does not exist there.

It will be much easier to use a full continuous set of orthogonal functions over the unit circle, a regular fourier series over $\theta$:

$$f(r,\theta)=C\ln r +\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty r^k(A_n \cos k \theta + B_n \sin k \theta)$$
You can take $A_0$ out of the sum, ignore positive $k$ because of the boundary conditions at the infinity, the same reasoning sets $C=0$. The rest is a simple fourier series:
$$f(r,\theta)=A_0+\sum_{k=1}^\infty r^{-k}(A_n \cos k \theta + B_n \sin k \theta)$$
Set $f(R,\theta)=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ and develop it into a fourier series. The symmetry sets $B_n=0$, and you are left to determine the $A_n$ coefficients.

EDIT:
note that I assumed your $\theta$ goes from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, but it's actually quite arbitrary, so you need to decide. If you let it go from $0$ to $2\pi$, you get a discontinuity at $\theta=0$ and you need the $B$ terms.

Comment: Well, I guess it is similar to what I meant to do with my sum, but the k/2. But, will the $R^{-k}$ give any problems in finding the coefficients $A_k$?

Comment: No problem, it's constant on the circle of boundary condition (it just rescales the coefficient). The fourier coefficient $a_n$ of the boundary condition $\cos\theta/2$ is $a_n=R^{-k}A_k$, which will give something like $(r/R)^{-k}a_n \cos k\theta$ for each term (see how nicely everything expresses with the ratio of the radius $r$ to the boundary radius).

Comment: Won't the fact that I am neglecting the terms with $k<0$ in the Fourier series of $\cos(\theta/2)$ give the wrong result?

Comment: The fourier terms are equivalent for $k>0$ and $k<0$, it's all duplicate. If you were solving for the inside of the circle, you would do exactly the opposite (remove negative powers because you know there are no poles at the middle). In essence, you need two boundary conditions (in your case one is at the infinity), so everything is just right.